# скролл при достижении 100% должен отображать еще +20 строк

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, прокрутка, table

Есть таблица, в который есть поиск по всей таблице и также реализованный через pipe  скролл. Так вот, когда скролл доходит до конца - активируются танцы с бубнами))))

Видимо проблема в том, что скролл при достижении 100% должен отображать еще +20 строк, но так как я установила значение для this.slice - он хочет прибавить, но "не могет".

***Пайп:***

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'slice',
  pure: false
})

export class SlicePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, num: number = 0) {
    return value ? value.slice(0, value.length - num) : value;
  }
}
```

***Сам код в компоненте:***

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {OfficeService} from '../office.service';
import {DataSource} from '../../shared/data-source';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-office-list',
  templateUrl: './office-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./office-list.component.css'],
})

export class OfficeListComponent implements OnInit {
  officeList = new DataSource([]);
  inputValue: any;
  slice: any;
  percent = 0;
  selected: any = null;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private officeService: OfficeService) {
    this.inputValue = '';
    this.slice = this.officeList.length - 20
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.officeService.getOfficeList()
      .subscribe((list) => this.handleResponse(list))
  };

  handleResponse(list: any) {
    this.officeList = new DataSource(list.offices);
    console.log(this.officeList.view()[0].items);
  }

  track(value: number) {
    this.percent = value;

  }

  clickToRow($event, office) {
    this.selected = office;
  }

  input() {
    if (this.inputValue !== '') {
      return this.slice = 0;
    }

    if (this.inputValue === '') {
      if (this.percent !== 100) {
        return this.slice = this.officeList.length - 20
      }
      else {
        return this.sliceSize()
      }
    }
  }

  sliceSize() {
    if (this.percent >= 100) {

      const len = this.slice

      for (this.slice; this.slice >= len - 20; this.slice--) {
      }
    }
    return this.slice
  }
}
```

Comment: покажите ваш компонент